# Two compiled python programs aren't connecting through pipes properly

Tags: python, terminal, pipe

I'm writing two very simple Python programs and trying connect them with pipes on Linux (CentOS). The first (called runner) just prints, and the second (called capture) is supposed to read those print statements from the runner program and print them itself. But when I run `python runner.pyc | tee capture.pyc`, nothing happens at my command line. It just hangs on some process and doesn't end.

I've done a bit of reading on pipes, but I can't find something relevant to my issue.

The code below includes some print statements just to verify which file is generating the print statement, and a sleep in the runner.py for 3 seconds so I don't generate an obscenely long output.

runner.py code:

```
import time

x = 0;
while True:
        print(x)
        x = x + 1
        print("running file")
        time.sleep(3)
```

capture.py code:

```
import sys
import time

while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    print(line)
    print("capture file")
```

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong or point me in the right direction?

Comment: You're using `tee` wrong (not sure why you use it at all): `command | tee filename` diverts a copy of the output of `command` into `filename`, so in this case you just overwrite the file `capture.pyc` and don't run the "capture" program at all.

Comment: In the simplest case you should run `python runner.py | python capture.py` (also not sure why you're running the `.pyc` files). With `tee` in between it should be `python runner.py | tee some_file.txt | python capture.py`

Comment: @mkrieger1 When I try the `python runner.py | python capture.py`, it still hangs at the command prompt without finishing. When I control-C out, it give me the message: `Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "capture.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "runner.py", line 9, in <module>
        time.sleep(3)
line = sys.stdin.readline()
KeyboardInterrupt
KeyboardInterrupt`

Comment: @mkrieger1 The accepted answer has addressed my issues. Thank you for pointing out I had multiple issues, I shall look into each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by a bunch of stuff (see comments on the question).  But in the runner programme, there is no flushing of the output.  Simply adding a `flush=True` (Python3 only) fixes this, and the running passes a `cat` test.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import time

x = 0;
while True:
    print(x)
    x = x + 1
    print("running file", flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Testing:

```
[bash] python3 ./runner.py | cat
0
running file
1
running file
...
```

Without the flush, there would probably be some output after a while, but I would not wait long enough to find out.  Typically flushing on a `print()` is done on end-of-line.  But with a pipe, on Linux at least, there's a 4 kilobyte buffer allocated.  There's a [way to un-buffer this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe).  But pipe-buffering is OS-dependant, so it's hard to know what's happening exactly.

Buffering is used because it's wasteful of CPU, processing data character by character instead of processing a whole block of data at once.

On the capture side, `sys.stdin.readline()` often returns a 0-byte read, so it's nicer to handle this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import time

while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if ( len(line) > 0 ):
        print( "Read %u: [%s]" % ( len(line), line.strip() ) )
```

Testing:

```
[bash] python3 ./runner.py | python3 ./capture.py
```

Gives:

```
python3 ./runner.py | python3 ./capture.py 
Read 2: [0]
Read 13: [running file]
Read 2: [1]
Read 13: [running file]
```

You will need a method to check for end-of-file on the capture side.

Comment: can you describe what the flushing does exactly, and why without it there is the issue?

Comment: @Mr.Mips - I added some simple notes.  It's hard to know *exactly* what's going on, because the observed operation is the nett result of Python, BASH, (probably libc) and Linux.